# Examples of immiscible or wall-climbing liquids

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, specific-reference, equilibrium

I am very interested in the physics of immiscible fluids. I would like to ask you if you know any source or list of experiments done by others, with two or three liquids. I am interested in the final equilibrium position, and its properties. For example, are there any two or three immiscible fluids, which when are put together in a cylindrical container reach an equilibrium state which is not radially symmetric? Are there any fluids that 'climb' on the walls of the container? If you have any reference of such experiments, please share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superfluids can "climb walls" and whatnot.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfluid

Superfluids have zero viscosity, but may have surface tension. Those with surface tension creep up walls in a capillary-like fashion (except here, they can creep up a single wall, whereas capillary action requires a tube).

I don't know about the immiscible liquids, though. What you are saying may be true for certain anisotropic liquids. But I'm not sure of this. Or maybe weird stuff will happen if you mix immiscible superfluids.

(Speculation follows) 
They may actually form alternating bands, when one liquid climbs up the wall, the other liquid climbs up the film of the first liquid on the wall. This may happen for two superfluids with different densities and surface tensions.